# The Trace Class Operators Form a Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, trace

I want examining the trace class operators $L_1(H)$ of a separable Hilbert space $H$ with the norm $||A||_1=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\lambda_n$ where $\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $(A^*A)^{1/2}.$  A text I am reading says that this space $L_1(H)$ is a Banach space with respect to that norm. It does not provide any proof though so I tried to but I am having difficulty.  I would appreciate if someone could either link me a proof or provide one here.  Thanks!

** Someone has posted below an answer using dual spaces.  I am still curious though if there is another way to do it more traditionally. **

Comment: Perhaps this could help: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pskoufra/OANotes-TraceClassOperators.pdf

Comment: I have the same question as you do. Have you found an answer?

Comment: http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/traceclass.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove that $L_1(H)$ is isomorphic to the dual of $K(H)$, the space of compact operators via the map
$$
A \mapsto \text{tr}(A\cdot \ )
$$
which implies that it is a Banach space. The proof should be available in most books on Operator theory - for instance, Murphy's book *C* algebras and Operator Theory* has a proof (See Section 4.2)

Comment: Is there an easy way to do it by showing a Cauchy sequence converges or absolute converge series implies the operator sum converges?  Or is this the only good way to do it?

Comment: Could you explain why the map you provide is an isometry?  I looked at that book and couldn't quite follow as it was on a higher level than I am.